# How to avoid Replace substituting subscripts?

Tags: replacement, subscript

I have a polynomial in $\rho$ with many parameters (I will omit the polynomial code in the Mathematica expressions below because it is too long):

$$
\rho ^3 J (\mu +1) \left[(A \delta  \tau _0+B (1-\delta ) \tau _1\right]+
\rho ^2 \left[\left(A \delta  \tau _0+B (1-\delta ) \tau _1\right) \left((\mu +1) V_B-J\right)+A (1-\delta ) J (\mu +1) \tau _0+B \delta  J (\mu +1) \tau _1+\delta  \mu ^2 \tau _0+(1-\delta ) \mu ^2 \tau _1\right]+
\rho  \left[A (1-\delta ) \tau _0 \left((\mu +1) V_B-J\right)-V_B \left(A \delta  \tau _0+B (1-\delta ) \tau _1\right)+B \delta  \tau _1 \left((\mu +1) V_B-J\right)+(1-\delta ) \mu ^2 \tau _0+\delta  \mu ^2 \tau _1\right]
-A (1-\delta ) \tau _0 V_B-B \delta  \tau _1 V_B
$$

Notice that $B$ is both a parameter and an index for $V_B$.

Say I saved this polynomial in `p`, then when I use `Replace` using `levelspec`, such as:

```
Replace[p, {δ -> 0, B -> 0}, 6]
```

Mathematica substitutes both $B$ in the coefficients and in the subscripts (why would anyone want this?):

$$
\rho  \left(A \tau _0 \left((\mu +1) V_B-J\right)+\mu ^2 \tau _0\right)+\rho ^2 \left(A J (\mu +1) \tau _0+\mu ^2 \tau _1\right)-A \tau _0 V_0
$$

Notice now there's a $V_0$ and a $V_B$. If I don't use `levelspec`, and use `/.` instead, all $B$ are replaced, in all indices (which is obvisouly what I do not want).

**How to avoid subscripts substitution?**

polynomial code is here:

`p=-A (1 - δ) Subscript[V, B] Subscript[τ, 0] -  B δ Subscript[V, B] Subscript[τ, 1] +  J (1 + μ) ρ^3 (A δ Subscript[τ, 0] +     B (1 - δ) Subscript[τ, 1]) + ρ ((1 - δ) μ^2 Subscript[τ, 0] + A (1 - δ) (-J + (1 + μ) Subscript[V, B]) Subscript[τ, 0] + δ μ^2 Subscript[τ, 1] + B δ (-J + (1 + μ) Subscript[V, B]) Subscript[τ, 1] - Subscript[V, B] (A δ Subscript[τ, 0] + B (1 - δ) Subscript[τ,1])) + ρ^2 (δ μ^2 Subscript[τ, 0] + A J (1 - δ) (1 + μ) Subscript[τ, 0] + (1 - δ) μ^2 Subscript[τ, 1] + B J δ (1 + μ) Subscript[τ, 1] + (-J + (1 + μ) Subscript[V, B]) (A δ Subscript[τ, 0] + B (1 - δ) Subscript[τ, 1]))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The real solution here is not to use `B` in a subscript, or better: not to use `Subscript` at all.

If you can't or don't want to do that, you can add an extra transformation rule for all `Subscript` expressions. Once `ReplaceAll` processes a subexpression, it won't touch it anymore.

```
expr = Subscript[x, B] + B;

expr /. B -> 1
(* 1 + Subscript[x, 1] *)

expr /. {s_Subscript :> s, B -> 1}
(* 1 + Subscript[x, B] *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica does not concern itself with **why** you might want to do something, it does **what** you indicate that you want done.

Convert the subscripts to strings prior to replacing `B`

```
p /. {Subscript[var_, sub__] :> Subscript[var, ToString[sub]], δ -> 0, 
  B -> 0}
```

Or, if you don't want the subscripts left as strings

```
p /. {Subscript[var_, sub__] :> Subscript[var, ToString[sub]], 
  δ -> 0, B -> 0} /. 
    {Subscript[var_, sub__] :> Subscript[var, ToExpression[sub]]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    p /. Subscript[a_, B] -> Subscript[a, x] /. {δ -> 0, 
   B -> 0} /. Subscript[a_, x] -> Subscript[a, B]
```

yielding the following

[image]

Have fun!